# OWL carousel autoplay по загрузке блока

Tags: javascript, html5, owl-carousel

Добрый день, есть скрипт карусельки, не могу додуматься как можно запустить автоплей, при попадании блока карусели на экран, а не при загрузке страницы, спасибо больше)

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
              loop: true,
              margin: 10,
              autoplay: true,
              autoplayTimeout: 2000,
              navText: [' ', ' '],
              lazyLoad: true,
              responsive: {
                  0: {
                      items: 1
                  },
                  600: {
                      items: 3
                  },
                  1350: {
                      items: 5
                  }
              }
          });
```

PS. Решил проблему, топорно конечно, но лучше чем ничего, если кому будет интересно:

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 10,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:2000,
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        navText: [' ', ' '],
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            1350: {
                items: 5
            }
        }
    });

  $(function () {
      var carousel = $('.owl-carousel');
      $(window).scroll(function() {
          var scrollEvent = ($(window).scrollTop() > (carousel.position().top - $(window).height()));
          if (scrollEvent ) {
              owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[2000]);
              console.log('hello screen')
          }
      });
  });

  $( document ).ready(function() {
      owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
  })
```

Comment: ...код покажите?

Comment: @Alexxosipov добавил, но толку-то, все равно это библиотечный код